# Concat 3 columns including extra string values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains 3 RGB values and I need a Computed Column that concatenates them together.

I've tried the below, but it says there is an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
"(" & RGB1 & "," & RGB2 & "," & RGB3 & ")"
```

Comment: You can also use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation in SQL Server uses `+`, not `&`:

```
'(' + RGB1 + ',' + RGB2 + ',' + RGB3 + ')'
```

But as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, you could also use SQL Server's [CONCAT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function:

```
CONCAT('(', RGB1, ',', RGB2, ',', RGB3, ')')
```

Also, strings in SQL should generally use single, not double, quotes, with acceptance of double quotes depending on the database.

Comment: Thanks Tim, CONCAT('(', RGB1, ',', RGB2, ',', RGB3, ')') did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
alter table t add computedcol as (RGB1 + ',' + RGB2 + ',' + RGB3);
```

Or, if you want the parentheses as part of the value:

```
alter table t add computedcol as ( '(' + RGB1 + ',' + RGB2 + ',' + RGB3 + ')' );
```

You need a complete `alter table` or `create table` statement.  The string delimiter is the single quote, not the double quote.  The string concatenation operator is `+`.

Comment: Thanks but errors with:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(' to data type tinyint.

Comment: @James . . . Your question should specify that the values are numbers.